# Gradient layer not showing up/working on an existing View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-graphics

I have a view with has another view (called swipeView) inside it. I'm trying to gradient color it using the CAGradientLayer - the code is below

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor, 
                  [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor, nil];

layer.frame = swipeView.bounds;

[swipeView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

I'm calling this in the ViewDidLoad method of the main view controller. I see no effect - the view I'm trying to color remains just the same. What am I doing wrong? Are there any other settings/ordering etc. I should know about?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the problem you're having, but I was just having the exact same symptom, and after a few hours of bafflement, I discovered my problem: I was creating a button, adding the gradient layer, and only later positioning the button.  Initially, the button dimensions are all 0, and when setting `layer.frame = swipeView.bounds;` I was setting the gradient layer to have 0 dimensions too.  I added code so that when sizing the button, I also sized the sublayers to match, and this fixed the problem.  I'm actually using MonoTouch, so the code looks like this:

```
btn.Frame = new RectangleF([the dimensions you need]);

foreach(var s in btn.Layer.Sublayers)
{
   s.Frame = btn.Bounds;
}
```

Maybe you're creating a view in code, and the view hasn't been sized or positioned, and so when you add the gradient it also has no size, and that's why you can't see it.  When the view  changes size (in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` maybe), resize the gradient layer and see if that solves it.

Comment: Many many years later, but want to comment anyway. This was my exact problem on a view that uses autolayout. Now I'm setting my gradients in `didLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.  Are you sure you hooked up your swipeView outlet correctly?  Debug your -viewDidLoad and verify that swipeView is not nil.  Also double check that the bounds (layer.frame) is something sensible.

It shouldn't be necessary, but you can try throwing in a `[layer setNeedsDisplay]` just to force the layer to render again, but I don't think that is your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor, 
              (id)[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor, nil];

layer.frame = swipeView.bounds;

[swipeView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

Make sure that swipeView is not nil and try swipeView.frame.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the nil terminator at the end of the colors array.

Also, I found insertSublayer did not work, with index either 0 or 1. Changing to simply addSublayer did the trick.